# Zend not autoloading models

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoloader

Ok, this is driving me nuts!

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
application
- modules
-- default
--- controllers
--- models
---- DbTable
---- Cachmapper.php
--- views
```

My config file looks like this

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```

The application seems to work, if I navigate to localhost, it correctly goes to the index controller.  But, for some reason it refuses to load any models.

Fatal error: Class 'Model_Cachmapper' not found in .............................../application/modules/default/controllers/IndexController.php on line 26

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try naming your class Default_Model_Cachmapper and see if that helps

Comment: Are you positive you are initializing the autoloader in your bootstrap's _initAutoload() method?

Comment: @Alistair - I have tried this and it gives the same result

@Mark - I think this might be the problem.  I have not declared the _initAutoload() method, but I was under the impression that you didnt need to...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working version (one of them, at least), for ZF 1.10.x and probably earlier, too.

index.php

```
<?php
// Define path to application directory

defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

application.ini - the relevant parts

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = Zend_
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

; Where will Zend_Application find the Bootstrap file
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

; Where are all the modules
resources.frontcontroller.moduledirectory = APPLICATION_PATH"/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
; And which is the default module
resources.frontcontroller.defaultmodule = "default"
```

and in application/Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

/**
 * Autoloader for the "public" module
 * 
 * @return Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader
 */
public function _initPublicAutoload()
{
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
                            array(
                                'namespace' => '',
                                'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'
                            )
                        );

    return $moduleLoader;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have got it working, I think it was something to do with the autoloader not being initialized.

On a side note, in the .ini file, I had to remove resources.frontcontroller.defaultmodule = "default" as it produced an error saying no controller directory had been specified...

Answer (score 3):

I am a novice ZF user, so this may not be 'correct' but I have had no problems using DB Models this way. 
My directory structure looks like this:

```
/
--/application
----/configs
----/controllers
----/forms
----/layouts
----/models
------/DbTable
```

In my application/public/index.php I have the following code:

```
...
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('Application_');

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader/Resource.php';
$resources = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
    'namespace' => 'Application',
    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
));

$resources->addResourceType('form','forms','Form');
$resources->addResourceType('model','models','Model');
$resources->addResourceType('dbtable','models/DbTable','Model_DbTable');
...
```

My application namespace is Application (if you couldn't tell).
My database models look like this (located in application/models/DbTable:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'User';
    protected $_primary = 'username';
}

class Application_Model_DbTable_WinLossTieScore extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'WinLossTieScore';
    protected $_primary = 'id';
...
}
```

Also, the relevant portions of application/configs/application.ini:

```
appnamespace = "Application"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
```

Comment: To any ZF experts out there: If this is incorrect, or shouldn't be in index.php I would be interested in knowing how to do it 'right'.

Comment: The addResourceType lines were the key for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add your models directory to your includePaths

I have:

```
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models"
```

I know, your models lies under your modules, but should be possible to do somehow. Maybe in the bootstrap instead of application.ini

**Att.: Rob**

Hi Rob,

Well i'm confused. Because i actually bought your book 'Zend Framework In Action'.

And in the bootstrap of the 'Places' app in the sourcecode, you have the following.

```
    set_include_path(get_include_path()
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/library/'
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/models/'
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/forms/'
    );

    include 'Zend/Loader.php';
    Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

I know that the source is written for an older ZF version. My current app i'm working on is based on Zend_Application, and if i remove the models folder from my includePaths, the loader can't find my models.

```
Warning: include_once(Users.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Programmer\wamp\include\Zend\Loader.php on line 146
```

Comment: You certainly don't need the models directory in your include path with the Zend loader.

Comment: @Rob: Please have a look at my response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a bootstrap class to the module as otherwise the module loader doesn't know about it.

```
class Default_Bootstrap extens Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

And store in applications/default/Bootstrap.php

http://akrabat.com/modules has some more info.